# Otimização da bateria

Tags: java, otimização

boa tarde!

Preciso que minha aplicação fique com a otimização de bateria desligada por default, ou seja, assim que instalada já conste na lista de aplicativos com otimização desligada. Esse seria o ideal, porém ainda não encontrei uma maneira de fazer isso.

Em minhas pesquisas achei uma solução que levaria o usuário direto a pagina de configurações, porém recebo erro "Activity not found".

Segue o código que estou usando:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName())));
```

Também criei uma solução que testa se essa função está desabilitada para o aparelho e caso não, informo o  usuário que o mesmo deve desabilitar, mas é só um quebra galho até conseguir fazer isso de forma automática. Segue:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            PowerManager pm = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(PowerManager.class);
            if (pm != null) {
                if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations("package:" + getPackageName())) {
                    //informa que precisa desabilitar a otmização de bateria
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Para acessar a aplicação será necessário desabilitar a otmização da bateria. " +
                            "Acesse: Configurações -> Aplicativos -> Coletor de dados -> Otmizar bateria.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Sai da aplicação
                    finish();
         }
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Não sou programador Android(Java), por isso perdoe-me caso esteja falando alguma besteira.

Att,

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução para o problema:

Declarar no manisfesto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

Invocar a tela logo após a instalação:

```
@SuppressLint("BatteryLife") Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, PermissaoCode.PERMISSAO_ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS.getValor());
```

Nesse caso criei um Enum que controla o total de permissões obrigatórias a serem fornecidas pelo usuário. Com essa implementação solicito a permissão do usuário para desabilitar a otimização da bateria e se o mesmo não fornecer, sigo solicitando até que o mesmo forneça, pois minha aplicação precisa disso.

Obrigado :D

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).